# Maximum number of files per drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, limit

I'm facing a problem of adding more file to a partition when there are too many of them, currently, I've approximately 10 million files + Linux file system, for some reason I want to add more files, but it keep saying that there is not enough space (I do have 30+ GB left though) any idea why is that happing and is it possible to be resolved?

Comment: `cd` to one of the directories in which you're trying to create files. Type `df -i .` and show us the results. The filesystem may not have any inodes left. How to fix that depends on the type of filesystem.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem! do you know how to specify the number of inodes ( during ubuntu installation for example)

Comment: you will want to create a new file system using mke2fs  using the -N xxxx  to set the number of inodes. I'd recommend also using the -n  switch  (which tells the command to run in test mode and not actually do anything ) until you get the results you are looking for.  also since this command has MANY switches i'd recommend  reading the full man page on it.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is that there's too many files in a single directory - directories can hold only a finite number of files. if that's not the problem, there are some other meta-data structures which can also limit the total number of files on disk.

You can differentiate between these two problems by checking if you can add files to another directory.